# mysql order by column name with space

Tags: mysql

here's what I'm trying to do

```
SELECT id,`Full Name`,`Social Number` FROM data ORDER BY 'Full Name' ASC
```

but it seems the order by `Full Name` ASC doesn't work. I think it's most probably because of the name which has space. any remedy to this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try enclosing them in back-ticks like

```
ORDER BY `Full Name` ASC
```

HTH

Comment: See also this bug report that also notes the issue when trying to use "double quotes" https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=29199

Answer (score 5):

try `ORDER BY 2 ASC` `2 refers to the second selected column which is FULL NAME`

Answer (score 3):

This is because you don't have to surround columns with quote `'`, you might use backtick `. Simply change as follow:

```
SELECT id,`Full Name`,`Social Number` FROM data ORDER BY `Full Name` ASC 
                                                         ^         ^
                                                         You need to change those
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `'` around the column name which is invalid

```
SELECT id,`Full Name`,`Social Number` FROM data ORDER BY `Full Name` ASC
```